# Correctness of cmath's pow() in GCC

Tags: c++, math, gcc, g++

**Code** [GCC, compiled with -O2 flag]

```
int main()
{
    vector< vector<int> > matrixa(8);
    int ff = 5;
    int s = pow(ff, matrixa.size());
    int ss = pow(double(ff), int(matrixa.size()));
    vector< vector<int> > comb(s);
    cout << ff << "^" << matrixa.size() << " = " << s << endl;
    cout << ss << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
5^8 = 390624
390625
```

I'm wondering why `s = 390624` when it should be `390625`. If I compile the code without -O2 flag, then `s = 390625`. Also, the casting for `ss` seems to correct the problem.

What's going on?

My OS is Windows 7 Ultimate x64. Not sure about the GCC version, it comes with Code::Blocks 10.05.

Comment: I think the one that comes is 4.4.1 IIRC.

Comment: `double pow(double, int)` is removed in C++11 BTW

Comment: Works correctly here (gcc-4.5.1, linux).

Comment: It probably computes powers by numeric approximation (probably newtons method).  It's possible that with optimization turned up it will run fewer iterations (and be less accurate).  What do you get if you do not cast the output to an int?

Comment: @wug: not sure what you're asking. i haven't cast any output.

Comment: @Donotalo `pow` returns a `double` (or `float`), by assigning the result to `int`, you cast implicitly.

Comment: MSVC 2010 doesn't even compile, cause your first `pow` is ambiguous overload.

Comment: @Wug: Newton’s method is not used for computing functions like these. Polynomial approximations are engineered in advance and then evaluated quickly. Minimax polynomials, with minor variations, are commonly used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because floating-point arithmetic is not perfect and when you do

```
int s = pow(ff, matrixa.size());
```

the result of `pow` is actually something more like `390624.99999` and when you truncate it to `int` it effectively is flattened down to 390624. If you expect an integer value there (a floating-point with .0 fractional part), you should probably round the result of `pow`.

Comment: This error is not caused by floating-point arithmetic. pow(5, 8) is exactly representable as a double, so a good math library should return exactly 390625. Even a library that only guarantees faithful rounding (less than 1 ULP) rather than correct rounding (no more than 1/2 ULP with ties rounded to even) would get the correct answer here. So, if pow is not returning the correct answer, the problem is library quality, not floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, but if floating-point arithmetic was absolutely ideal (which is not and it was the point of my answer), even the (poor) algorithm behind that implementation of `pow` would not produce any deviations. So one can actually say it was caused by IEEE floating-point arithmetic. But I agree with you completely, it's the implementation of `pow` to blame in this particular case..

Comment: Ideal arithmetic, in the sense that each operation produced exact mathematical results, would not cause pow to produce correct results. This is because floating-point arithmetic provides only addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, square root, and some utility operations. These are insufficient to compute pow (for general arguments; obviously specific cases like pow(5, 8) can be computed), because the arithmetic operations can compute only rational functions extended with square roots. Therefore, pow and other math library functions must be approximated, even with perfect arithmetic.

Answer (score 5):

Try assigning the result to a `double` and output it (with possible bigger `std::setprecision`) settings. You will see that due to rounding errors, the value will be something like `390624.99999999999` (or similar).

Casting to an int truncates the fractional part, thus leaving you with `390624`. Use `std::round` to get the desired result.